# Earth Rotational Vector and Orbital Inclination

Tags: orbital-mechanics, launch, orbit, inclination

I'm doing a project regarding orbital launches and i'm kinda confused about how to calculate orbital inclination from launch sites. I've simplified my model so I can ignore fuel and the rocket equation as I'm only interested in delta-v.

I'm a bit confused on how to account for earth rotational speed at different Latitudes for the orbital inclination with the lowest delta-v requirements. I know that the orbit with the lowest delta-v will have an orbital incliation the same as the latitudes of launch but am unsure how to prove it ?

I am aware that I'm going to have to use spherical trigonomet

Comment: I'm unclear on exactly what you are asking here. Do you want a proof, or do you want to know how to set up your model?

Comment: @ZubinJIAN your question is also unclear to me as well. It's hard to tell from these few sentences exactly what it is that you do know how to do and where you are stuck. Can you add some equations or at least more detail on how far you've gotten. It might help to break this up into a few, more narrowly focused questions.

Comment: @OrganicMarble and . I want to be pointed at some resources that explain the relationship between latitude and required orbital velocity with more detailed maths

Comment: Good info here: https://www.orbiterwiki.org/wiki/Launch_Azimuth